# Get a particular value from String

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

I want to remove particular value from my string. My string can be of any length. E.g.

string 1:

> {"ABC":1,"ABC_DT":-1,"ABC_DBQty":0,"ABC_DSQty":0,"ABC_LMT":1,"ABC_DT":-1,"CTSD":"TEST","SD":1,"TE":***23***}

string 2:

> {"ABC":1,"ABC_DT":-1,"ABC_DBQty":0,"ABC_DSQty":0,"ABC_LMT":1,"ABC_DT":-1,"CTSD":"TEST","TE":***23***}

I want this 23 as a result. How can I get this in SQL Server 2014?

Comment: What distinguishes those characters from any others in the string? Is it that they follow `"TE":` or that they are the last digits in the string or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(500) = '{"ABC":1,"ABC_DT":-1,"ABC_DBQty":0,"ABC_DSQty":0,"ABC_LMT":1,"ABC_DT":-1,"CTSD":"TEST","TE":23}'
SET @string = REVERSE(@string)

SELECT REVERSE(
                SUBSTRING(@string,2,CHARINDEX(':',@string)-1-1)
              )  --return: 23
```

Comment: Please provide some description to your answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX) = '{"ABC":1,"ABC_DT":-1,"ABC_DBQty":0,"ABC_DSQty":0,"ABC_LMT":1,"ABC_DT":-1,"CTSD":"TEST","TE":23}'
,@posA INT = 0
,@posB INT = 0
,@res VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SET @posA = PATINDEX('%"TE":%}', @str) +5; 
SET @posB = CHARINDEX('}', @str, @posA+1);  

SET @res = SUBSTRING (@str ,@posA, @posB-@posA )  

SELECT @res AS 'STR_res', CAST(@res AS INT) AS 'INT_res'
```

Comment: some explanation to your answer will be helpful to others

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

use the JSON_VALUE function:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014

(unfortunately available since 2016)

Comment: That link says "The requested page is not available for SQL Server 2014. You have been redirected to the newest product version this page is available for."

Comment: @Danev Thanks. But i want this for SQL server 2008 also.